# Sort an array based on another array element’s class

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am looking for way to sort elements in an array based on the classes of the elements in another array. I have:

```
order = [String, Integer, NilClass ,TrueClass]
arry = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, true, false, nil, 34, nil, 'Hello', 'World']
```

In `order`, the order of the elements is dynamic. The result should be:

```
result_arry = ['Hello', 'World', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34, nil, nil, true, false]
```

How can I sort `arry` based on the class of the elements in `order`?

I tried:

```
hash = arry.group_by  {|n| n.class } 
# => {Fixnum=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34], TrueClass=>[true], FalseClass=>[false], NilClass=>[nil, nil], String=>["Hello", "World"]}
```

Comment: Your `order` array contains strings, not classes.

Comment: And what happened to `false`?

Comment: false will at last in array as FalseClass is not part of order Array. I have updated my question. Thanks @Stefan

Comment: @Stefan , regarding your first comment, I mean array elements's class. So 'Hello' class is String in Ruby. Do it make sense?

Comment: I mean the elements of your `order` array: `'Integer'` (with quotes) is a string, whereas `Integer` (without quotes) is a class.

Comment: @ Stefan , I got you. but this is how question was asked to me in interview. Though I have updated my question.

Comment: Does the order in `array` have to be preserved when it is a tie? For example, can the order among `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34` be randomly changed among one another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works:

```
arry.sort_by{ |v|
    order.map{ |c|
        v.is_a?(Object.const_get(c)) ? -1 : 1
    }
}

# ["Hello", "World", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34, nil, nil, true, false]
```

`Object.const_get(c)` converts the string to class.

Comment: Good answer, but I think describtion why this works is in order.   For example the usuage of `const_get` would not be clear to anyone.  Please edit your answer, don't place it into comments

Comment: :0) much better but `const_get` is not used only for that e.g. it can be used to get PI value `Math.const_get(:PI)`. It would be nice if you would explain how it works internally

Comment: I get a different output (since `sort_by` isn't stable), what Ruby version are you running?

Answer (score 4):

Using `group_by` is a good approach, because it keeps the element's order:

```
hash = arry.group_by(&:class)
#=> {
#     Integer => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34],
#     TrueClass => [true],
#     FalseClass => [false],
#     NilClass => [nil, nil],
#     String => ["Hello", "World"]
#   }
```

We can use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to sort the hash by its keys based on each key's [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-index) in the `order` array. If a class is missing from `orders`, we use the array's [`size`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-size) as a fallback to have it sorted last:

```
sorted = hash.sort_by { |k, _| order.index(k) || order.size }
#=> [
#     [String, ["Hello", "World"]],
#     [Integer, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34]],
#     [NilClass, [nil, nil]],
#     [TrueClass, [true]],
#     [FalseClass, [false]]
#  ]
```

Finally, [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) extracts each element's [`last`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-last) part:

```
sorted.flat_map(&:last)
#=> ["Hello", "World", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34, nil, nil, true, false]
```

---

You can also use `sort_by` without prior grouping, but it may shuffle elements with the same class:

```
arry.sort_by { |e| order.index(e.class) || order.size }
#=> ["World", "Hello", 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 34, nil, nil, true, false]
```

This is because `sort_by` is not stable.

In order to fix it, we have to take their indices into account:

```
arry.sort_by.with_index { |e, i| [order.index(e.class) || order.size, i] }
#=> ["Hello", "World", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34, nil, nil, true, false]
```

---

If you also want to match subclasses (e.g. make `Integer` match [`Fixnum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html) in older Ruby versions), you have to pass a block to `index`:

```
order.index { |cls| e.is_a?(cls) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting, *per se*, is not necessary.

```
missing_classes = arry.map(&:class) - order
  #=> [Symbol, FalseClass]
arry.group_by(&:class).values_at(*(order + missing_classes)).flatten
  #=> ["Hello", "World", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34, nil, nil, true, :cat, false]
```